# g_hash_table_lookup in a recursion

Tags: c, linux

I have written the following toy program to test "g_hash_table_lookup()" within a recursion:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <string.h>

void f_recursive(GHashTable *htable, int level){
    char key[] = "test_key";
    char value[] = "test_value";
    char *returned_value;

    if(level > 0){
        f_recursive(htable, level - 1);
    }
    else if(level==0){
        g_hash_table_insert(htable,&key[0],&value[0]);
    }

    returned_value = g_hash_table_lookup(htable,&key[0]);
    printf("Level=%d, Returned Value=%s\n",level, returned_value);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int i=3;
    GHashTable *Hash_Table;

    Hash_Table = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash,g_str_equal);
    f_recursive(Hash_Table, i);
}
```

---

The goal of this code is simply to call a recursive function that at each level of the recursion looks up in the Hash Table the value of a key that was inserted only at the lowest level of the recursion. My expectation would be that at each level of the recursion I can recover the value inserted at the lowest level, and so the expected output of this program should be:

```
Level=0, Returned Value=test_value
Level=1, Returned Value=test_value
Level=2, Returned Value=test_value
Level=3, Returned Value=test_value
```

However, this is not what happens. Instead I get the following:

```
Level=0, Returned Value=test_value
Level=1, Returned Value=([��`�
Level=2, Returned Value=(null)
Level=3, Returned Value=(null)
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain me why I am able to retrieve the inserted value in the hash table only at the level in the recursion where I do the insertion.

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html):

> Note that neither keys nor values are copied when inserted into the GHashTable, so they must exist for the lifetime of the GHashTable.

That means that this:

```
g_hash_table_insert(htable,&key[0],&value[0]);
```

Doesn't copy `key` or `value`, the hash table just stores the pointers. However, `key` and `value` are allocated on the stack:

```
char key[] = "test_key";
char value[] = "test_value";
```

So your `&key[0]` and `&value[0]` pointers are only valid for the duration of the function. Once you get out of your recursion, you have a hash table full of invalid pointers and that gives you a bunch of garbage and undefined behavior.

You should be using [`g_hash_table_new_full`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new-full) with freeing functions for both keys and values and then duplicating your keys and values when you call `g_hash_table_insert`; you could use [`g_strdup`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup) to duplicate the keys and values and [`g_free`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-free) as the `key_destroy_func` and `value_destroy_func` arguments to `g_hash_table_new_full`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have thought about that. For my understanding, does "g_hash_table_new_full()" keep a copy of key and value instead of a pointer to them ? Or is it that the duplicates created by "g_strdup()" are somehow kept "alive" until explicitly freed by "g_free"?

Comment: @Dani: No, the hash table just copies the pointers not what they point to. `g_strdup` is pretty much a `malloc` and `strcpy`, that's why you need to use the long form of the hash table constructor (the version with the two freeing functions) or make sure you clean up the memory manually.